# How to plot calibration curve for multi-class problems?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multiclass-classification

How to plot calibration curve for multi-class problems, for example the available example on python plots it for 2 classes but here in the e-book link it is done for multi-class[book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tHBZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=calibration%20curve%20for%20mnist&source=bl&ots=msQlL5ZF9R&sig=RVPpl-NnEg4OR1KNE60_i5edf50&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6oq2NmabbAhUWT48KHdCCAS8Q6AEIbTAK#v=onepage&q=calibration%20curve%20for%20mnist&f=false)

how can I do so in python or R?